# How does Laravel find plural of models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If I have a Model "Dog", Laravel will link it to the table "Dogs". Always the plural.
Now, if I have a Model "Person", it tries to find the table "People" - also the plural. But how does Laravel know the plural when it's more than just adding a "s"?
Is there a tabel with all english nouns?

Comment: Probably some version of this : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php

Comment: The answer marked correct below is no longer relevant. The correct answer for v.5 is below, however.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Laravel 4

In the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php` you'll find something like `str_plural($name)`  and `str_plural` is a helper function which uses `Str::plural` method and in this case, this method looks like this:

```
public static function plural($value, $count = 2)
{
    return Pluralizer::plural($value, $count);
}
```

So it's obvious that, `Str::plural` uses class `Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer.php` and there you'll find how it actually works. Just read the source code. There is a separate word mapping for `irregular word forms` with others:

```
// Taken from Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer
public static $irregular = array(
    'child' => 'children',
    'foot' => 'feet',
    'freshman' => 'freshmen',
    'goose' => 'geese',
    'human' => 'humans',
    'man' => 'men',
    'move' => 'moves',
    'person' => 'people',
    'sex' => 'sexes',
    'tooth' => 'teeth',
);
```

Comment: well put my friend ... well put :)

Comment: Same for Lara 6

Comment: 'status' => 'statuses' 
( in case you were wondering, like me )
( just tested with php artisan tinker - calling Str::plural('status', 2) )

Answer (score 29):

### Laravel 5 & 6

The Alpha's answer was for Laravel 4.

To give credit where it is due I wanted to update the answer for Laravel 5+.

`Pluralizer` now extends from [doctrine/inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/1.3.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php) to avoid re-inventing the wheel. This library contains some basic rules, e.g.

```
(m|l)ouse         => _ice
(buffal|tomat)o   => _oes
...all else...    => append 's'
```

Followed by some "uninflected" (i.e. singular and plural are the same)

```
deer, fish, etc.
```

And finally the irregular rules, e.g.

```
man  => men
ox   => oxen
```

From the documentation:

> Doctrine inflector has static methods for inflecting text.
>
> The methods in these classes are from several different sources collected
>   across several different php projects and several different authors. The
>   original author names and emails are not known.
>
> Pluralize & Singularize implementation are borrowed from CakePHP with some modifications.

So it's interesting how much all of the frameworks borrow and reuse from one another.