# Does Laravel migration take grammar seriously for Model?

Tags: php

I speak English, but not that good when it comes to grammar.

Now this question is about `Laravel Framework`.

Lately I've been developing a project using Laravel, normal day. But then, I started to make a migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_quizs_table --create=quizs
```

Created a few create query using `php artisan tinker`, yes all goes fine.

But then I refresh my migration just for curiosity, `php artisan migrate:refresh`, and here's what I get when I try to load pages using table `quizs`, after I:

1. Created a Quiz Model, `App\Quiz.php` from artisan,
2. try Eloquent technique to retrieve simple database `::all()` query.

---

`The Error on my browser:`

```
There is an error ... with 'quizzes' something.
```

---

At this point, I learned that the plural of quiz is **quizzes**, not `quizs`. Is Laravel that strict on that, especially Model, since I noticed, Model use Singular without those `s`-es such as Quiz, Note, Book etc.

I have to figure out my English just to solve this.

```
Sadly, I don't have any log as `too much tinkering` corrupt my project.
```

But that is what I recall clearly, for I learned the plural of `quiz` from Laravel, thanks I guess. I believe you can recreate the issue too by creating `quizs` table, with wrong grammar.

Comment: <br>
This answer will help you: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943663/how-does-laravel-find-plural-of-models,"check this answer")