# Laravel seed issue, laravel is looking for plural table name

Tags: laravel

i've just started learning Laravel and I have problem generating seed for my test table.

Console error says:
"Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.testms' doesn't exists..."

My table is called "testm" - I have no idea why it looks for testm**s**

TestmFactory.php

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Testm::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        return [

        'test' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

TestmTableSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TestmTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
      factory(App\Testm::class, 5)->create();
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
  public function run()
    {

        $this->call(LinksTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(TestmTableSeeder::class);
    }
```

app/Testm.php

```
class Testm extends Model
{
   // Below line fixed my code :-)
     protected $table = 'testm';
     protected $fillable = [
        'test'

    ];
}
```

Comment: `laravel` is the name of the database that the tables are in. Check your database connection's `database` value in `config/database.php`.

Comment: Laravel looks for the plural of the model name as the table

Comment: So you want to override this functionality and define the table parameter explicitly in the model `Testm.php` with the following code `protected $table = 'testm';`

Comment: Add this to your model `protected $table = 'testm';`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Laravels documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.

And in order to explicitly define the table name in the model, `Testm.php` in your case, you would want to add the following code to the class:

```
protected $table = 'testm';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense now. I'd be looking at my files for this for ages without your help :D

Comment: @riten no problem! I highly suggest using Laravel's documentation. The search box on it makes finding stuff like this super fast!

Comment: Yeah, I just had no idea what to look for. I mean I didn't even realize it's looking for plural, I was thinking about some misspelled name in my files.

Comment: Yeah, it can get confusing, especially because it doesn't exactly make it clear *why* it's looking for it that way. If you want an easy way to generate a model, with a migration, you should take a look at using `php artisan make:model Test -m` in the command line. It saves you time from having to write both by hand.

Comment: I just found more informations about plural here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943663/how-does-laravel-find-plural-of-models

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your model

```
protected $table = 'testm';
```

Comment: Yep thats correct, however "Derek" answer was a little bit more educative so I marked it as answer

Comment: No issues   i could also learn how to answer in detail 